# CMake unable to locate JNI package on new Mac Mini

Tags: macos, cmake, java-native-interface

CMake is unable to find the package JNI when running on a new Mac mini.  The cmake configuration files work on an older MacBook Pro, Windows, and various Linux's.  Here are the gory details:

```
cmake version 3.26.3
```

```
java version "20.0.1" 2023-04-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
Darwin  22.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 21:01:02 PST 2023; 
root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T8112 arm64
```

```
JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home
```

```
ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  74986 Mar  7 09:13 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h
```

```
CMake Debug Log at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindJNI.cmake:434 (find_path):
  find_path called with the following settings:

    VAR: JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH
    NAMES: "jni.h"
    Documentation: JNI include directory
    Framework
      Only Search Frameworks: 1
      Search Frameworks Last: 0
      Search Frameworks First: 0
    AppBundle
      Only Search AppBundle: 0
      Search AppBundle Last: 0
      Search AppBundle First: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_INSTALL_PREFIX: 1

  find_path considered the following locations:

  The item was not found.
```

And, yes, I have tried setting CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK to "never", which has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in CMake's FindJNI module, which relied on the JavaVM framework which was removed in XCode 12.2.

The corresponding [CMake bugticket](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23364) contains a patch for the FindJNI module, but I haven't tested whether it actually works.

Comment: Unfortunately, the patch didn't do the trick.